# Table cell text is aligned slightly to the left of the center

Tags: html, css, css-tables

In an HTML table using center alignment, the text is aligned slightly to the left of the center. How can I remedy the situation?

```
td { border:1px solid #000; text-align:center; white-space: nowrap; }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Which browsers have you tested it in?

Comment: Firefox 3. However, it needs (hard requirement) to be supported by IE6.

Comment: What does the content of a cell look like? Is there a carriage return after the number? Non-breaking space?

Comment: @ppecher Why don't you upgrade to 3.5 or 3.6?

Comment: Is there any more border or padding for td in the css ? (it's a suggestion, but I think that Joel gave you the answer :) )

Comment: With only the code you provided, the text is aligned in the center perfectly: Firefox3, IE7, IE8, Opera 11, Google Chrome 9, etc. Have you inspected the markup and style in Firebug, Developer Tools, et al?

Comment: @ppecher The image that you provided works in FF3 and IE6. `:)`

Comment: The markup of the table is generated with a growing Javascript string in an array, which is returned at the end with return array32.join("\r\n");
I use Firefox 3.6
I will now investigate the potential white characters and the external CSS that are linked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @ppecher Try `array32.join('')`. No need for new lines in HTML source code.

Answer (score 0):

Just so it's listed as an answer ... Some things to consider in troubeshooting:

1. Often when tables are aligned improperly, there is whitespace behind it. Your `</td>` tag must appear immediately after the final element with no spaces for exact precision in such centering.
2. Sometimes data elements that are extracted as strings will contain either leading or trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc). These need to be trimmed before being displayed to make sure that the content you want is all you get.
3. A good method for checking spacing and styling issues is Google Chrome's "inspect element" feature. It will display the exact code being rendered and the styles being applied immediately to the element. This is handy particularly when dealing with JavaScript generated elements (as one of your comments suggests you have), AJAX, or similar elements that have a shifting nature within the browser.